# points2grid error: (points,tolerance,round) - grid has empty columns/rows in dimension

Tags: raster, r, sp

I have seen answers to this on R-sig-geo, but I am still unclear on the solutions provided in different forums.

Below, I am trying to convert a dataframe to a raster that can later be used in ArcMap (and for which I would like to build an attribute table later on).

```
#Below, I have a dataframe with 4 columns, containing lat/long       
out=cbind(y,x,logDist=round(log10(d)*100),logSpeed=round(log10(d/50)*100))
out <- as.data.frame(out)

###Converting a dataframe to a raster in R

coordinates(out)=~x+y
proj4string(out)=CRS("+init=epsg:32643") # set the projection
out = spTransform(out,CRS("+init=epsg:32643"))

#Tell R that this is gridded:
gridded(out) = TRUE
```

However, I get the following warning messages:

1: In points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :
  grid has empty column/rows in dimension 1

2: In points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :
  grid has empty column/rows in dimension 2

Any suggestions on how I solve these warning messages would be really helpful

If I continue to plot(raster) and writeRaster, I get a TIFF file with holes in them. How do I solve this?

EDIT: (Following Spacedman's comment)

Shown below is an image of how the data looks like when I coerce it to be a raster.

[image]

Comment: It seems that the points in your data.frame do not form a regular, dense grid. Package raster may have better methods, e.g. rasterize, but you need to give it a raster in advance.

Comment: Also, why do you set the projection string to epsg 32643 and then transform the coordinates to epsg 32643? That doesn't do anything. If the x and y really are lat-long then you should set the projection string to epsg:4326 before projecting that whatever 32643 is. And just because you have a regularly spaced grid in one coordinate system doesn't mean you'll have one in another because the earth isn't flat. Can you plot your data, or some of it, or look at the numbers and see if they do form a grid?

Comment: @Spacedman I have tried what you suggested, to no avail. Here's the thing, I used a Python script earlier and the CRS is already in epsg 32643 - which is the UTM Zone 43N. So I don't need to sptransform it. But, when I plot the data, there are holes in the raster. Shall add that to the question.